# Can't do cd in xv6 while using emulator QEMU

Tags: qemu, xv6

I installed qemu emulator with os xv6. 
I trying to compile a project that written in c that includes: makefile,
2 c files, and header. 
I opened the qemu terminal and I trying to change directory with the command cd
to get to the files and it said to me: "cannot cd"

[image: qemu console]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @EugeneSh. [os xv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xv6)

Comment: What does `ls /` report?

Answer (score 0):

As @melpomene points out, when you run `ls /` you will see that you get something very different than what you get when you run `ls /` outside QEMU. Why, because QEMU is emulating a computer that is running the xV6 OS. This emulated computer/OS has no idea about (or access to) your local file system. It only knows of the files it gets via `fs.img` (see the [xV6 Makefile](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/34f060c3dcf3bf3dde683df9ff9872bc9f1d5d14/Makefile#L185)).

It is also the reason why various commands entered fail - `sudo`, `su`, `make`. None of these programs exist in xV6.